# What is the significance of the art in "Children of Men"?

Tags: symbols, children-of-men

In the movie "Children of Men", Theo goes to see his cousin Nigel to ask a special favor. [During the ride](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEvRk2tL82U) the King Crimson song "In the Court of the Crimson King" is heard, probably an allusion to halls of power.

In addition, many people have seen the flying pig over Battersea power station as a [clear reference to Pink Floyd's album "Animals"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCQG-4n9kqo), and by way of extension to Roger Water's characterization of pigs as existing  ["...at the top of the social ladder, the ones with wealth and power; they also manipulate the rest of society..."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigs_(Three_Different_Ones))

In these scenes which seem so heavy with symbolism, what is the significance (if any) of the use of Michelangelo's David, and Picasso's Guernica?